# Reverse the ways divs are displayed in mobile view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a view in desktop which looks like attached image. I am using bootstrap.
I want the mobile view to look like the second image. How do i achieve it. If you see it dropdown come to the bottom.
[image]

Desktop View

Mobile view

[image]

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is using Bootstrap's built in column ordering classes, `.col-sm-push-*` and `.col-sm-pull-*`

Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Here's the code.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Button 3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9">
    <select class="form-control"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/mHPiPxZ6YY

Comment: - It works well.. What is it doing actually. Can you just explain as i am newbie to bootstrap

Comment: Sure. First thing to note is that bootstrap 3 is mobile first, so in this example I define the divs in the order they will show on a mobile. Then for larger devices I use the 'pull' class to move the dropdown 9 columns to the left, and the 'push' class to move each button 3 columns to the right. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bootstraper 3.0 and up, you can add the pull-right class to each columns. Click "Full Page" to check the desktop view.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pull-right col-md-3 col-xs-12">Button</div>
    <div class="pull-right col-md-3 col-xs-12">Button</div>
    <div class="pull-right col-md-3 col-xs-12">Button</div>
    <div class=" pull-right col-md-3 col-xs-12">Dropdown</div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Hacher** Hi there. You could do it this way, with the `hidden-xx` classes.
Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4a5s7uu/)**.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 hidden-xs btn btn-success"><h3>Dropdown</h3></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 btn btn-primary"><h3>Button</h3></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 btn btn-primary"><h3>Button</h3></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 btn btn-primary"><h3>Button</h3></div>  
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg btn btn-success"><h3>Dropdown</h3></div>
```

[image]

**You could also use a little jquery**

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9u1dcwzb/)**.
Just resize and hit **run** or **refresh** etc for it to change.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 btn btn-success" id="first"><h3>Dropdown</h3></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 btn btn-primary"><h3>Button</h3></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 btn btn-primary"><h3>Button</h3></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 btn btn-primary" id="last"><h3>Button</h3></div>
<script>   
   if ($(window).width() < 767) {
       $("#first").insertAfter("#last");
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: it's not necessary to duplicate the dropdown twice in the markup